# SQL Query to only Select rows in a specific sequence

Tags: sql, sequence

I would like to perform the following on a result dataset in SQL.

I have a specific table, and in the table I have a column "Crossing_Direction", as seen below. The values are listed just like this.

| CROSSING_DIRECTION |
| --- |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |

[image: Image 1]

I would like to query the column according to a particular sequence. The values that are not within the sequence should not be shown.

The result should show:

| CROSSING_DIRECTION |
| --- |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |
| DEPARTURE |
| ARRIVAL |

[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

I would like a SQL query that would place the column ‘Crossing_Direction’ in the sequence according to “DEPARTURE” then “ARRIVAL”. **Where there is a "DEPARTURE" there must be a "ARRIVAL"**

The code that I have used so far is:

```
WITH SequencedRows AS (
    SELECT 
        Crossing_Direction,
        LAG(Crossing_Direction) OVER (ORDER BY Crossing_Direction) AS previous_value
    FROM [dbo].[Immigration_upload4]
)
SELECT s1.Crossing_Direction
FROM SequencedRows s1
WHERE s1.Crossing_Direction = 'ARRIVAL' AND previous_value = 'DEPARTURE'
```

However, I haven't gotten any satisfactory results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: Including example DDL and DML will make this much easier to solve. Consider: `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Column1 INT, Column2 DATE, ...);
INSERT INTO @Table (Column1, Column2, ...) VALUES
(1, '2024-01-01', ...), 
(2, '2024-02-01', ...);` In addition please tag the appropriate SQL product. The answer may be different for various dialects (SQL Server, Oracle, PostGreSQL, etc).

Comment: Also, you need to update your question with the SQL you've managed to write so far and explain where you are stuck. Unfortunately, this is not a free code-writing service

Comment: And need to explain why one row takes precedence over another in your logic. For example, why remove row 5 rather than row 6?

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the below query to achieve it**

```
SELECT xxx.srno, fname, direction FROM
(SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS srNo,fname,direction FROM   stackoverflowtest  WHERE  fname IN(SELECT fname
FROM   [stackoverflowtest]
GROUP  BY fname HAVING Count(fname)%2 = 0)) xxx
WHERE  ( srno%2 = 1 AND direction = 'Departure' ) OR ( srno%2 = 0 AND direction = 'Arrival' )
```

[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaYQP.png)

Please modify your column accordingly I am using attached test table structure. You can improve the above query for the performance.

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of how the code works. And links to images are just as ill-advised for answers as they are for questions. Assuming that there will always be an even number of errant records seems optimistic, OP would need to confirm that. This would omit the entire person they had 8 well formed pairs and a 9th errant.